# How to Handle Deserialization Exception & Converting to New Schema with Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, dead-letter, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am have trouble understanding how to properly handle a deserialization exception within Spring Cloud stream. Primarily because the framework implemented does not support headers and the DLQ is supposed to be a separate schema than the original message. So the process flow needs to be: consume message -> deserialization error -> DlqHandler -> serialize with NEW schema -> send to DLQ

The documentation linked below doesn't give a good idea on if that is even possible. I have seen quite a few examples of SeekToCurrentErrorHandler for Spring-Kafka but those to my knowledge are different implementations and do not match with how I could properly get the deserialization error and then have a section for custom code to serialize into a new format and move from there.

My main question is: Is capturing the deserialization exception and reserializing possible with spring cloud streams (kafka)?

[Spring Cloud Documentation for DLQ](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-dlq-processing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not using the binding retry or DLQ properties.

Instead, add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean and customize the binding's listener container with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` configured for the retries you need and, probably, a subclass of the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` using an appropriately configured `KafkaTemplate` and possibly overriding the `createProducerRecord` method.